# Creating a new column from a matrix

Tags: r

I have an **n by 2** matrix, for example:

```
x <- matrix(1:4, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
```

I have to create a new column which will store the result

```
(a11+a12)-a22, (a21+a22)-a32, ...
```

and so on. `a32` is not there so it is considered as `0`. Is there an easy way to do this in R ?

I have tried to use the `apply()` function with no luck. The desired output is a column with values

```
0
6
```

Comment: you can evaluate the operation you want on the row and store it, and after that, you can add a new column using cbind.

Comment: @RonakShah only the addition will take place, thats y the second value of the colmn is 6

Comment: I am not still clear about your expected output. Can you expand the example and include more rows and show expected output ?

Comment: The `6` should be `2+4-a33`, so where is the `a33`?

Comment: @DarrenTsai if a33 is not there it is considered as 0 , if at all it is there then the value should be subtracted

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i used apply and got the sum of the rows and tried subtracting the lagged value from the sum

Comment: This doesn't make sense, if your matrix is n by 2 you will never have a33. Do you mean a32?

Comment: @CharcoHui i am sorry , i meant a32, i have changed it in the question , thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
x <- matrix(1:4, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)

# obtain the row sum of x
rs = rowSums(x)

# obtain the last column from the matrix
x = x[,ncol(x)]

# remove the first value and add a 0 at the end 
# since your last value will always be 0
x = x[-1]
x = c(x, 0)

rs - x
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , that worked , i was trying to do the same with apply to get the sum and then use lag , however lag does not lag my variable by 1 .. wonder why ?

Comment: You need to read the help page on `lag`. If his worked for you please accept this as an answer.

Comment: @narayanpr23 there are two functions named `lag()` in R, one is `stats::lag()` and the other is `dplyr::lag()`. The former is used to time series data, and the latter is what you look for.